# How can I initialize a bean with @RefreshScope from Spring Boot Integration tests?

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I've been scratching my head for a couple of hours.

Spring Cloud Netflix autoconfigures an Eureka client. The following snippet comes from the sources of EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(value = EurekaClient.class, search = SearchStrategy.CURRENT)
@org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope
@Lazy
public EurekaClient eurekaClient(ApplicationInfoManager applicationInfoManager, EurekaClientConfig config, EurekaInstanceConfig instance) {
  applicationInfoManager.getInfo(); // force initialization
  return new CloudEurekaClient(applicationInfoManager, config,
                    this.optionalArgs, this.context);
        }
```

This bean will only be initialized when my Spring Boot application triggers an application event.

Considering I am running JUnit integration tests, that kind of event won't occur.

Here the unit test :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ReferentialClientTest.class)
public class InstrumentClientIT {
    @Resource
    private InstrumentClient instrumentClient;

    @Test
    public void testInstrumentClient() {
        instrumentClient.findOne(455540l).getName();
    }
}
```

The InstrumentClient is a Feign client that depends on EurekaClient.

Here's the Test configuration class.

```
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ReferentialClientTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReferentialClientTest.class, args);
    }
}
```

How can I make sure that the EurekaClient is properly initialized without wiring it into my integration test ? (That is the only work around I have found yet).

Comment: Have you tried annotating your test class with `@WebAppConfiguration`,  It ensures Spring loads a web app context for your test.  `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` doesn't seem to imply this by default.  I could be wrong, so I didn't supply this as an actual answer.

Comment: And we got ourselves a winner ! `@WebAppConfiguration` didn't worked. But `@WebIntegrationTest` did the trick ! I can finally make sense of that annotation ! Just give an explanation answer and I'll accept it ;)

thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as discovered, you need to annotate your class with `@WebIntegrationTest`.

Comment: @WebIntegrationTest was indeed the answer. It managed to generate the applicationEvent which triggered the Bean initialization. Many thanks !

Comment: These deprecated annotations

@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = arrayOf(BootApplication::class))
@WebIntegrationTest("server.port=8081")
in Spring Boot 1.5+ are equivalent to

@SpringBootTest(classes = arrayOf(BootApplication::class), properties = arrayOf("server.port=8081"))
@WebAppConfiguration